# How to detect Page Refresh in Blazor Server?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am performing some database operation when a user changes tha page, leaves the page, closes the browser. I have implemented a Dispose() function for this, so it's working fine.

But the same Dispose() function gets called even if user Refreshes the page (F5). how can I detect this in Blazor Server?. I don't want to perform that 'database operation' if user refreshes the page.

I have no idea how can I do this?

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        lockingService.Unlock(componentName, CurrentUserID);      
        lockingService.NotifierLockingState -= RefreshUserInterface!;
    }
```

Is there any way to detect page refreshes in Blazor Server?

Comment: Not possible unless you write some horrendously complicated tracking system. Whether you exit and go away or exit and return, you are exiting the SPA session.  Unless you are doing the database calls on a `Singleton` service [which you shouldn't be], then the database operation is lost when the session resets. If you are doing long running operations you should be using cancellation tokens and Unit of Work DbContexts provided by a DbContextFactory, .

Comment: I haven't tried it, but if you were willing to have a Singleton service that tracked the last page visited by IP, you could probably catch incoming requests in Middleware, and check them against the last page visited.

Comment: If you're oily doing a query, then why worry too much.  If you are doing processing/updating then lock the page and navigation until it completes.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to detecting page refreshed such as user state,js interop and etc..
you can use a custom component that implements IDisposable interface and wraps your page content. This component can have a flag that indicates whether it is disposed by a refresh or not, and you can set this flag using JavaScript interop using window.onbeforeunload event and call a C# method using JSInvokable attribute